# Owl Carousel reponsivo

Tags: wordpress, carousel, owl-carousel

Tenho um site no wordpress no qual instalei o plugin Owl Carousel (v0.53), com um carousel horizontal de 14 itens, sendo 4 visíveis por vez.

No desktop, o `width` das thumbnails é de `298px`, enquanto que no mobile, especifiquei no css do tema `175px`. Enquanto que no primeiro está tudo normal, nas versões mobile após o fim dos 14 itens, sobra um espaço em branco (que é exatamente o tamanho de + 14 itens vazios).

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema? Imagino que seja algo relacionado à imagem abaixo, no `transform: translate3d`, mas não sei como modifica-lo exatamente.

[image: erro]

Tentei instalar o Owl Carousel 2, que diz ser responsivo, mas o wordpress acusa falha na instalação sempre que eu tento instalá-lo.

Quando coloco o `width` das thumbnails no mobile por `350px`, ele fica normal, porém apenas com 1 item, enquanto que queria que fosse possível ter 2 por vez.